# Onnx installation issue on linux

Tags: python, linux, onnx

I tried to install onnx on my linux machine and encountered issue when I use `python3 -m pip install onnx`as

```
/tmp/pip-install-7ajubmjo/onnx_08cda1ef5f1d460ab7b455210cf3083e/onnx/defs/sequence/defs.cc: In function ‘bool onnx::BuildSequenceMapBodyFunc(const onnx::FunctionBodyBuildContext&, const onnx::OpSchema&, onnx::FunctionProto&)’:   /tmp/pip-install-7ajubmjo/onnx_08cda1ef5f1d460ab7b455210cf3083e/onnx/defs/sequence/defs.cc:675:40: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<onnx::ValueInfoProto>’ and ‘int’)
           seq_at_node.add_output(g_inputs[inputIndex].name());
[ 95%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnx.dir/onnx/version_converter/helper.cc.o
  CMakeFiles/onnx.dir/build.make:830: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/onnx.dir/onnx/defs/sequence/defs.cc.o' failed
```

The `protobuf` was installed via `sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler libprotobuf-dev` and my environment is:

```
- python=3.6
- ubuntu=18.04
```

Another related issue seems that the compilation cannot not find `pybind11` as:

```
Generated: /tmp/pip-install-7ajubmjo/onnx_08cda1ef5f1d460ab7b455210cf3083e/.setuptools-cmake-build/onnx/onnx-ml.proto
    Generated: /tmp/pip-install-7ajubmjo/onnx_08cda1ef5f1d460ab7b455210cf3083e/.setuptools-cmake-build/onnx/onnx-operators-ml.proto
    Generated: /tmp/pip-install-7ajubmjo/onnx_08cda1ef5f1d460ab7b455210cf3083e/.setuptools-cmake-build/onnx/onnx-data.proto
    -- Could NOT find pybind11 (missing: pybind11_DIR)
    -- pybind11 v2.9.1
    --
    -- ******** Summary ********
    --   CMake version             : 3.10.2
    --   CMake command             : /usr/bin/cmake
    --   System                    : Linux
    --   C++ compiler              : /usr/bin/c++
    --   C++ compiler version      : 7.5.0
    --   CXX flags                 :  -Wnon-virtual-dtor
```

even though it's already installed via `pip install pybind11`.

Any thoughts on how to move forward with this issue ?

Comment: try pip install pybind11[global] https://stackoverflow.com/a/70403316/7007942

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade you protobuf version seems the issue is with default Ubuntu 18.04 repo protobuf package.

simmilar issue was reported on opencv forum.
[github issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/18110#issuecomment-675791384)

> Installation of protobuf 3.5.1 fixes this, maybe error in the original
> install process. I installed protobuf 3.5.1 from [this release](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.5.1/protobuf-all-3.5.1.tar.gz)

#### Install steps

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```